# Excel - Only show true results (skip results if false)

Tags: excel, countif

I'm working with a list of devices with IP Addresses. Some of those IP addresses have hostnames and some do not. The IP address is listed in column A and if they have hostnames, the hostname is listed in column B.

On a separate worksheet, I would like to display only the IP addresses that do not have a hostname. I have found a formula that does this (tweaks are welcome).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet1'!A2:A39914,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF('Sheet1'!A2:A39914, 'Sheet1'!B2:B39914),ROW('Sheet1'!B2:B39914) - ROW('Sheet1'!B2) + 1),ROWS('Sheet1'!B2:B2))),"")
```

What I would like to also do is remove duplicates. I only want to show these results once. What would need to be added in order to only show one instance of the IP address?

Comment: You could just use the `Advanced Filter`.  It has a parameter for `Unique Records`

Comment: Ideally, I'm looking to integrate it into the formula.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just doing this in Access. It took me like 5 seconds to figure out how to do what I was trying to achieve.